# Split string in GSP grails

Tags: grails, groovy

How to split a string and get first words?

**studentController.groovy**

```
def student = {
     def ex = new ArrayList() 
     ex[0]= "Steven | ABCDEF0123456" 
     ex[1]= "Steven | ABCDEF0123456" 
     //student's value

     [studentlist:ex] //send to gsp
}
```

**student.gsp**

```
<g:each in="${studentlist}" status="i" var="stdnt">
   <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
      <td>${stdnt}</td> //i want this show "Steven"
      <td>${stdnt}</td> // and this show ABCDEF0123456
   </tr>
</g:each>
```

How can I get the first word and second word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Java's `String.split()` method:

```
List ex = "Steven | ABCDEF0123456".split('\\|')*.trim()

[studentlist:ex] //send to gsp
```

If you know there are only two items in the list, then you can reference them via `studentlist[0]` and `studentlist[1]`.  It's a little unclear what you expect from the controller currently (a list of lists?):

```
<td>${studentlist[0]}</td>
<td>${studentlist[1]}</td>
```

Comment: how about array mr.igor?